# Pseudo-inverses equivalence

Tags: pseudoinverse

I  am wondering what is the relation between Pseudo-inverses and the following:

$Ax=b$, when $A$ is singular, then $x = \left( A^T A \right)^{-1} \left(A^T b \right)$.

Then, what is the difference between $\left(A^T A\right)^{-1} A^T$ and $A^+$?

Comment: @algae, would like to know what's the syntax of typing math formula properly? I fail to find the relevant link yet...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Linearly_independent_columns

Comment: But keep in mind that the formula you use is only valid when the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, which is certainly not true if $A$ is square and singular. And you can't write either that $x=\dots$: It's not an *inverse*.

Comment: @HingWong You can typeset equations using LaTeX. If you edit your own post (this post), you will see what it looks like. For more information check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @algae, thx so much! it helps! :)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut, oh i see i see! Thx!!